# How does this isPrime method in java using regex work

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if a number is a prime with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795065/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime-with-regex)

Here is the code:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    return !new String(new char[n]).matches(".?|(..+?)\\1+");
}
```

Can someone walk me through what the regex translates to in English and explain why it works?

Comment: I assume this is _not_ homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall what a prime number is and what it *isn't*. First of all, this negates the regex match, so the regex matches on *composite* numbers.

It first creates a string of length *n*, its characters are irrelevant as long as they are matched by `.`.

That means the number is either `0` or `1` (which are not prime):

```
.?
```

or it must have two divisors greater than one:

```
(..+?)\1+
```

The first divisor is handled by the capturing group `(..+?)` which will match at least two characters (i.e. represent a number greater than or equal to two). The `+?` is a lazy quantifier so it will try to match as little as possible; this likely just speeds up the process.

The `\1` is a backreference matching the exact same thing the first group matched, this is repeated at least once using `+`. This repetition represents the second factor of the number to check. So if the group matches *a* characters and the `\1+` repeats this *b* − 1 times you got yourself a representation of *a* ċ *b*. If this matches, *n* was a composite number and thus not prime.

Regexes do backtracking in trying to create a match, so if it doesn't work with `\1` containing two characters it will try with three, four, etc. until either a match is found or the group captures more than half the string.

So, e.g. for 14 the group would match two characters and `\1` would then be repeated seven times, mimicking the factors of the number to test. Since this matches it has factors other than itself and one and thus isn't prime.

5 on the other hand would try with two characters in the group, then three and giving up there (since `aaa` cannot exist more than once in `aaaaa`). Thus five is prime.

[Here is a more thorough explanation](http://deltalambda.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/regular-expression-prime-numbers/), although once you figure it out mathematically it's blindingly obvious and trivial.

Answer (score 1):

`.?` is one or none character

`(..+?)` is at least 2 characters but with a reluctant qualifier (meaning it tries to match as little characters as possible) and the parentheses means it's a capturing group

`\\1+` is repeating the first capturing group at least once

this means that the regex will only match strings with 0, 1 or any non trivial multiple (2 or more) of 2 or more

in other words it matches if n can be written as `k*l` with both `k` and `l` greater or equal than 2 (one of the properties of a non-prime number)

however it's easier to just do

```
for(int i=2;i*i<=n;i++)if(n%i ==0)return false;
return true;
```

it does the exact same thing but stops sooner (on `sqrt(n)` instead of `n`)

Comment: I think the point of that regex is not that it's easier or faster to do otherwise. The point is more that it can be done.