# How to vertically align the output in Java using boolean?

Tags: java

I am trying to align my output so that it looks like this:

```
11
13
15
17
```

Right now, it only prints out like 11,13,15,17. What should I do with my code to make it properly aligned? I tried adding \n after true which didn't work.

#### Code:

```
boolean test {
    
    int z, 
    for (z = 10, i <= 30; i++) {
        if ((z % z== 0) && (z % 1 == z))
            }               
        System.out.println(true); //number is prime
        System.out.println(false);//number is not prime
```

Comment: `z % z== 0` doesn't make much sense, since the result will always be 0. And `z % 1 == z` will always be 0 as well, so it will never be equal `z`

Comment: It also won't compile, since the `if`'s condition is immediately followed by a closing curly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()` for the integer, and `println()` for the `boolean`.

`PrintSteam.println()` ends the printing with a terminal newline `'\n'`.

See this:

```
int z;
for (z = 10; z <= 30; z++) {
    System.out.print(z);
    System.out.print(' '); // Add spacing between number and boolean.
    if ((z % z == 0) && (z % 1 == z))
        System.out.println(true); //number is prime
    else
        System.out.println(false);//number is not prime
}
```

[Here is an online ideone code demo!](http://ideone.com/6qKzS8)

But you can also print in a simpler **loop**:

```
for (int z = 10; z <= 30; z++)
    System.out.printf("Is %s prime? %s\n", z, (z % z == 0) && (z % 1 == z));
```

However the algorithm for checking if it's a prime is incorrect, you can use a modified method [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2795065/3622940):

```
for (int z = 10; z <= 30; z++)
    System.out.printf("Is %s prime? %s\n", z,
            !new String(new char[n]).matches("(..+?)\\1+"));
```

In source code of `PrintStream.println()`:

```
/**
 * Prints a boolean and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(boolean)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>boolean</code> to be printed
 */
public void println(boolean x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: like this? System.out.print(true \n);

Comment: Why you recommend using `print` instead of `println` when he wants every entry on his own line and not next to each other?

Comment: @Nordehinu you may edit your first sentence :). And add a delimiter after printing the number. `11false` doesn't look good :).

Answer (score 1):

You want to revise your code as shown below. You should have been checking against "i" not "z"

```
public class TestPrime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int z = 1; z < 40; z++) {
            if (isPrime(z)) {
                System.out.println(" " + z + " is prime");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int z) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 30 && i < z; i++)
            if ((z % i) == 0 && z != i) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;              
            }
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```