# Regular Expression for conditional replacement of parts of string in US phone number mask (Swift compatible)

Tags: regex, swift, replace, nsregularexpression

I try to come up with regular expression patter that fulfills such requirements.

1. it is US phone number format  wit 3 groups
2. I have input strings like this
   `(999) 98__-9999` here there is extra `_` at the end of second section which I want to delete

`(999) 9_8_-9999` here there is extra `_` at the end of second section I want to delete

`(999) 9_-9999` here if second group length is < 3  and ends with _ there should be added `_` to pad second group to `9__` (3 characters)

`(999) 98-9999` here if second group length is equal to 3 or it ends with digit there shouldn't be any modifications

To sum up: 
If `secondGroup.length > 3 && secondGroup.lastCharacter == '_'` I want to `remove` this last character 
else if `secondGroup.length < 3 && secondGroup.lastCharacter == '_'` I wan to `append "_"` (or pad wit underscore to have 3 characters in total)
`else leave` second group as in the input string.

The same should be applied to first group. The difference are the different delimiters i.e. (xxx) in first group and \sxxx- in second group

Here is my Swift code I have used to achieve it in brute force way by manually manipulating the string: (length 4 instead of 3 takes into account first delimiter like `(` or `\s`. )

```
var componentText = ""
        let idx1 = newText.index(of: "(")
        let idx2 = newText.index(of: ")")
        if let idx1 = idx1, let idx2 = idx2 {
            var component0 = newText[..<idx1]
            var component1 = newText[idx1..<idx2]
            if component1.count  > 4 && component1.last == "_" {
                component1.popLast()
            } else if component1.count < 4 && component1.last == "_" {
                component1.append("_")
            }
            componentText += "\(component0)\(component1))"
        } else {
            componentText = newText
        }
        let idx3 = newText.index(of: " ")
        let idx4 = newText.index(of: "-")
        if let idx2 = idx2, let idx3 = idx3, let idx4 = idx4 {
            var component2 = newText[idx2..<idx3]
            component2.popFirst()
            var component3 = newText[idx3..<idx4]
            var component4 = newText[idx4...]
            if component3.count > 4 && component3.last == "_" {
                component3.popLast()
            } else if component3.count < 4 && component3.last == "_" {
                component3.append("_")
            }
            componentText += "\(component2) \(component3)-\(component4)"
        } else {
            componentText = newText
        }
        newText = componentText != "" ? componentText : newText
```

I think that using regular expression this code could be more flexible and much shorter.

Comment: "I think that using regular expression this code could be more flexible and much shorter." -- I don't think so. Read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions).

Comment: If the code is currently working you may want to post on [codereview.se] to see if they suggest using regex.

Comment: [Example code that is worse with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795065/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime-with-regex).

Comment: Your replacement logic is fairly complex, and I would rather just see some sample input and output data which covers the cases.

Comment: It is not so complex. There are 3 groups each one consisting od digits and underscore. I need to modify 1st group and 2nd group. There are 2 reasons to modify each group (in both groups there are the same 2 cases). 1.) when group length > 3 and it ends with underscore then pop last underscore, 2.) when group length < 3 and it ends with underscore then append underscore at the end, in all other cases leave group as in input

Comment: The third example contains ***2*** digits in the second part. Is it OK? Try [`(\)\s*\d(_))\b|(\)\s*\d[\d_]{2})_\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ODVcPn/1) to replace with `$1$2$3`