# Regex not being greedy enough

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, regex-greedy

I've got the following regex that was working perfectly until a new situation arose

```
^.*[?&]U(?:RL)?=(?<URL>.*)$
```

Basically, it's used against URLs, to grab EVERYTHING after the U=, or URL= and return it in the URL match

So, for the following

http://localhost?a=b&u=http://otherhost?foo=bar

URL = http://otherhost?foo=bar

Unfortunately an odd case came up

http://localhost?a=b&u=http://otherhost?foo=bar&url=http://someotherhost

Ideally, I want URL to be "http://otherhost?foo=bar&url=http://someotherhost", instead, it is just "http://someotherhost"

EDIT: I think this fixed it...though it's not pretty

```
^.*[?&](?<![?&]U(?:RL)?=.*)U(?:RL)?=(?<URL>.*)$
```

Comment: Oh, the irony... your question says "not greedy enough", while the problem is caused by the `.*` being too greedy :)

Comment: @MvanGeest, yah, I forgot that the .* would be greedy, I had been trying to make the other half "greedier"... never occured to me that the .* was the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The issue

The problem is not that `.*` is not being greedy enough; it's that the *other* `.*` that appears earlier is *also* greedy.

To illustrate the issue, let's consider a different example. Consider the following two patterns; they're identical, except in reluctance of `\1` in second pattern:

```
              \1 greedy, \2 greedy         \1 reluctant, \2 greedy
              ^([0-5]*)([5-9]*)$           ^([0-5]*?)([5-9]*)$
```

Here we have two capturing groups. `\1` captures `[0-5]*`, and `\2` captures `[5-9]*`. Here's a side-by-side comparison of what these patterns match and capture:

```
              \1 greedy, \2 greedy          \1 reluctant, \2 greedy
              ^([0-5]*)([5-9]*)$            ^([0-5]*?)([5-9]*)$
Input         Group 1    Group 2            Group 1    Group 2
54321098765   543210     98765              543210     98765
007           00         7                  00         7
0123456789    012345     6789               01234      56789
0506          050        6                  050        6
555           555        <empty>            <empty>    555
5550555       5550555    <empty>            5550       555
```

Note that as greedy as `\2` is, it can only grab what `\1` didn't already grab first! Thus, if you want to make `\2` grab as many `5` as possible, you have to make `\1` reluctant, so the `5` is actually up for grab by `\2`.

#### Attachments

- [The first pattern on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/iTvWHtxmip)
- [The second pattern on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/DsTRYMHX8E)

#### Related questions

- [Regular expression: who's greedier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565924/regular-expression-whos-greedier)

---

#### The fix

So applying this to your problem, there are two ways that you can fix this: you can make the first `.*` reluctant, so ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/Ks5wB7LNBx)):

```
^.*?[?&]U(?:RL)?=(?<URL>.*)$
```

Alternatively you can just get rid of the prefix matching part altogether ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/YTm9YuLQVi)):

```
[?&]U(?:RL)?=(?<URL>.*)$
```

Comment: Reluctant? I usually call it non-greedy. So indeed, the first `.*` is too greedy.

Comment: @MvanGeest: I learned regex through Java, and that's what they call it (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Comment: @polygenelubricants: OK, I met regexes in Perl, and Learning Perl uses non-greedy. It's also in a very old Perl FAQ: http://www.perl.com/doc/FAQs/FAQ/oldfaq-html/Q1.3.html But yeah, who cares what they're called? (A person searching the web desperately, of course...)

Comment: Nice edit and further explanation, I'd upvote and accept this answer again if I could