# how can i read the vale of first = sign(or the the value of middle = sign) not the last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i read the answer regarding the answer of this code

```
function delete_subscriber(){
var id=this.href.replace(/.*=/,'');
this.id='delete_link_'+id;
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this subscriber?'))
$.getJSON('delete.php?ajax=true&id='+id, remove_row);
return false;
}
```

but i want the value read through regular expression  of the 1st equalsign or middle equal sign  not the last
for example i want the value
"I am some text before" or "and I am in between"
from the line below

```
"I am some text before=and I am in between=and I am after"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `split` rather than regex:

```
var parts = this.href.split('=');
var id = parts[0]; //before first =  "I am some text before"
var id = parts[1]; //after first =  "and I am in between"
var id = parts[2]; //after second =  "and I am after"
```

If you want text before and after the first = sign:

```
var id = this.href.split('=').splice(0, 2).join('='); //I am some text before=and I am in between
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The short answer

The problem is greediness of `.*` in your original pattern `.*=`.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Use reluctant `.*?=` instead
- Use negated character class instead `[^=]*=`

#### See also:

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/) (long answer with illustrative examples)