# I don't understand a regexp

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm following along a tutorial (Ruby) that uses a regex to remove all html tags from a string:

`product.description.gsub(/<.*?>/,'')`.

I don't know how to interpret the `?`. Does it mean: "at least one of the previous"? In that case, wouldn't `/<.+>/` have been more adequate?

Comment: Note that HTML attributes may contain plain `>` characters. Your regular expression doesn’t consider that.

Comment: I was following along a tutorial, which (as you point out) uses a simple approach to the problem. I was more interested about the way *? works.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532 - I covered this in detail with illustrative examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, it make `*` lazy.

`1*` - match as many `1`s as possible.
`1*?` - match as few `1`s as possible.

Here, when you have `<a>text<b>some more text`, `<.*>` will match `<a>text<b>`.
`<.*?>`, however, will match `<a>` and `<b>`.

See also: [Laziness Instead of Greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

Another important note here is that this regex can easily fail on valid HTML, it is better to use an HTML parser, and get the text of your document.

Answer (score 6):

By default `.*` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) which means that it matches as much as possible. So with `.*` the replacement would change:

```
This <b>is</b> an <i>example</i>.
     ^-------------------------^
```

to

```
This .
```

If you use a question mark *after* a quantifier it makes it non-greedy, so that it matches as little as possible. With `.*?` the replacement works as follows:

```
This <b>is</b> an <i>example</i>.
     ^-^  ^--^    ^-^       ^--^
```

Becomes:

```
This is an example.
```

This is different from the more common use of `?` as a quantifier where it means 'match zero or one'.

Either way if your text is HTML you should use a HTML parser instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Quantifiers such as `*` are greedy by default. This means they match as much as possible. Adding `?` after them makes them lazy so they stop matching as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

that's the best website I found about regex after the regex library:

http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html

Hope that helps!