# How to represent a fix number of repeats in regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a better way to represent a fix amount of repeats in a regular expression?

For example, if I just want to match exactly 14 letters/digits, I am using `^\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w$` which will match a word like `UNL075BE499135` and not match `UNL075BE499135AAA`
is there a handy way to do it? I am currently doing it in Java, but I guess this may apply to other language as well.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For Java:

[Quantifiers documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

X, exactly n times: X{n}
X, at least n times: X{n,}
X, at least n but not more than m times: X{n,m}

Comment: That is for any perl-compatible regular expression.

Comment: @BipedalShark the 'bound' is defined in POSIX regexp standard. See `man 7 regex` on most *nix systems. Most common regex languages including Perl's derive at some point from POSIX's.

Comment: for those who didn't figure out how to do "repeat up to m times", you can use X{0,m}

Answer (score 36):

The finite repetition syntax uses `{m,n}` in place of star/plus/question mark.

From [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
X{n}      X, exactly n times
X{n,}     X, at least n times
X{n,m}    X, at least n but not more than m times
```

All repetition metacharacter have the same precedence, so just like you may need grouping for `*`, `+`, and `?`, you may also for `{n,m}`.

- `ha*` matches e.g. `"haaaaaaaa"`
- `ha{3}` matches only `"haaa"`
- `(ha)*` matches e.g. `"hahahahaha"`
- `(ha){3}` matches only `"hahaha"`

Also, just like `*`, `+`, and `?`, you can add the `?` and `+` reluctant and possessive repetition modifiers respectively.

```
    System.out.println(
        "xxxxx".replaceAll("x{2,3}", "[x]")
    ); "[x][x]"

    System.out.println(
        "xxxxx".replaceAll("x{2,3}?", "[x]")
    ); "[x][x]x"
```

Essentially anywhere a `*` is a repetition metacharacter for "zero-or-more", you can use `{...}` repetition construct. Note that it's not true the other way around: you can use finite repetition in a lookbehind, but you can't use `*` because Java doesn't officially support infinite-length lookbehind.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*` and `.*?` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)
- [`regex{n,}?` == `regex{n}`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184484/regexn-regexn/)
- [Using explicitly numbered repetition instead of question mark, star and plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032593/using-explicitly-numbered-repetition-instead-of-question-mark-star-and-plus)

  - Addresses the habit of some people of writing `a{1}b{0,1}` instead of `ab?`

Answer (score 21):

`^\w{14}$` in Perl and any Perl-style regex.

If you want to learn more about regular expressions - or just need a handy reference -  the [Wikipedia Entry on Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is actually pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

In Java create the pattern with `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w{14}$");` for further information [see the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Or use the short-hand: `"UNL075BE499135".matches("^\\w{14}$");`