# Regex in SPARQL: Why [[:alnum:]] doesn't return matches?

Tags: regex, sparql, wikidata

I want to find the Wikidata resource corresponding to a specific website. This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?instanceOfLabel ?website
WHERE
{
    ?resource wdt:P856 ?website.
        FILTER (REGEX(str(?website), 'http(s)?://(\\w.)?smh.com.au/$')) .
  }           
}
```

(link [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fresource%20%3FinstanceOfLabel%20%3Fwebsite%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fresource%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Fwebsite.%0A%20%20%09%09FILTER%20%28REGEX%28str%28%3Fwebsite%29%2C%20%27http%28s%29%3F%3A%2F%2F%28%5C%5Cw.%29%3Fsmh.com.au%2F%24%27%29%29%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20%0A))
which doesn't return any result. This is not what I would expect since

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?instanceOfLabel ?website
WHERE
{
    ?resource wdt:P856 ?website.
        FILTER (REGEX(str(?website), 'http(s)?://www.smh.com.au/$')) .           
}
```

(link [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fresource%20%3FinstanceOfLabel%20%3Fwebsite%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fresource%20wdt%3AP856%20%3Fwebsite.%0A%20%20%09%09FILTER%20%28REGEX%28str%28%3Fwebsite%29%2C%20%27http%28s%29%3F%3A%2F%2Fwww.smh.com.au%2F%24%27%29%29%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20%0A))

Comment: What do you expect is the meaning of `(\\w.)`? I mean what do you expect to match against it and how does it reflect the website scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern `\w` (written `\\w` to escape `\`) means **one** letter, but you expect **three** `w` letters as I understood.

To match three `w` you should use

```
'http(s)?://(w{3}.)?smh.com.au/$'
```

Though, what's the problem in using `www`?

```
'http(s)?://(www.)?smh.com.au/$'
```

If you want any three letters use

```
'http(s)?://(\\w{3}.)?smh.com.au/$'
```

Maybe you want just more than `0` of any letters?

```
'http(s)?://(\\w+.)?smh.com.au/$'
```

I guess, this answer will help you: [How to represent a fix number of repeats in regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3261581/1305036)