# Why doesn't ? work as an optional repetition specifier in this pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match inputs like

```
<foo>
<bar>
#####<foo>
#####<bar>
```

I tried `#{5}?<\w+>`, but it does not match `<foo>` and `<bar>`.

What's wrong with this pattern, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: inputs like what? Could you please show the input pattern you're after and the regex you tried in different lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### On `?` for optional vs reluctant

The `?` metacharacter in Java regex (and some other flavors) can have two very different meanings, depending on where it appears. Immediately following a repetition specifier, `?` is a reluctant quantifier instead of "zero-or-one"/"optional" repetition specifier.

Thus, `#{5}?` does not mean "optionally match 5 `#`". It in fact says "match 5 `#` reluctantly". It may not make too much sense to try to match "exactly 5, but as few as possible", but this is in fact what this pattern means.

---

#### Grouping to the rescue!

One way to fix this problem is to group the optional pattern as `(…)?`. Something like this should work for this problem:

```
(#{5})?<\w+>
```

Now the `?` does not immediately follow a repetition specifier (i.e. `*`, `+`, `?`, or `{…}`); it follows a closing bracket used for grouping.

Alternatively, you can also use a non-capturing group `(?:…)`in this case:

```
(?:#{5})?<\w+>
```

This achieves the same grouping effect, but doesn't capture into `\1`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Question Mark for Optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) - yes, but only with proper placement
  - [Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
  - [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
  - [Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)
- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): `X{n}?` : *X*, exactly *n* times

#### Related questions

- [`regex{n,}?` == `regex{n}` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184484/regexn-regexn) (absolutely NOT!)
- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)

---

#### Bonus material: What about `??`

It's worth noting that you can use `??` to match an optional item reluctantly!

```
    System.out.println("NOMZ".matches("NOMZ??"));
    // "true"

    System.out.println(
          "NOM NOMZ NOMZZ".replaceAll("NOMZ??", "YUM")
    ); // "YUM YUMZ YUMZZ"
```

Note that `Z??` is an optional `Z`, but it's matched reluctantly. `"NOMZ"` in its entirety still `matches` the pattern `NOMZ??`, but in `replaceAll`, `NOMZ??` can match only `"NOM"` and doesn't have to take the optional `Z` even if it's there.

By contrast, `NOMZ?` will match the optional `Z` greedily: if it's there, it'll take it.

```
    System.out.println(
          "NOM NOMZ NOMZZ".replaceAll("NOMZ?", "YUM")
    ); // "YUM YUM YUMZ"
```

#### Related questions

- [method matches not work well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202120/method-matches-not-work-well)

  - unlike other flavors, Java `matches` a pattern against the *entire* `String`

Answer (score 2):

Place your `#` match in a subpattern:

```
(#{5})?<\w+>
```