# method matches not work well

Tags: java, regex

I don't understand why with this regex the method returns false;

```
Pattern.matches("\\bi", "an is");
```

the character i is at a word boundary!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Java, `matches` attempts to match a pattern against *the entire string*.

This is true for [`String.matches`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), [`Pattern.matches`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [`Matcher.matches`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29).

If you want to check if there's a match somewhere in a string, you can use `.*\bi.*`. In this case, as a Java string literal, it's `".*\\bi.*"`.

#### `java.util.regex.Matcher` API links

- [`boolean matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29): Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

---

#### What `.*` means

As used here, the dot `.` is a regex metacharacter that means (almost) any character. `*` is a regex metacharacter that means "zero-or-more repetition of". So for example something like `A.*B` matches `A`, followed by zero-or-more of "any" character, followed by `B` ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/5el1iIBzbX)).

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and [The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)

Note that both the `.` and `*` (as well as other metacharacters) may lose their special meaning depending on where they appear. `[.*]` is a character class that matches either a literal period `.` or a literal asterisk `*`. Preceded by a backslash also escapes metacharacters, so `a\.b` matches `"a.b"`.

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Literal Characters and Metacharacters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

---

#### Related problems

Java does not have regex-based [`endsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29), [`startsWith`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29), and [`contains`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). You can still use `matches` to accomplish the same things as follows:

- `matches(".*pattern.*")` - does it contain a match of the *pattern* anywhere?
- `matches("pattern.*")` - does it start with a match of the *pattern*?
- `matches(".*pattern")` - does it end with a match of the *pattern*?

---

#### `String` API quick cheat sheet

Here's a quick cheat sheet that lists which methods are regex-based and which aren't:

- Non-regex methods:

  - [`String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))
  - [`String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))
  - [`boolean startsWith(String prefix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))
  - [`boolean endsWith(String suffix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))
  - [`boolean contains(CharSequence s)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))
- Regex methods:

  - [`String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
  - [`String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
  - [`String[] split(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
  - [`boolean matches(String regex)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))

Comment: where do you find the syntax of .* ??? Thanks

Comment: You mentioned pretty much every string or regex method except [find](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29). :)

Comment: @Matthew: yeah I specifically only list the ones in `java.lang.String`. I mean, I can write an essay if I really want to cover everything (e.g. compiling). I'm not sure if I really should, though.

Comment: Better use `contains(CharSequence s) ` with Strings that contain symbols such as `%`. I ran into this problem and `matches(".*pattern.*")` returned false when comparing `aaa (%)` with the exact same String, although `equals(String s)` and `contains(CharSequence s) ` returned true.

Answer (score 5):

The *whole* string has to match if you use matches:

```
Pattern.matches(".*\\bi.*", "an is")
```

This allows 0 or more characters before and after.  Or:

```
boolean anywhere = Pattern.compile("\\bi").matcher("an is").find();
```

will tell you if any substring matches (true in this case).  As a note, compiling regexes then keeping them around can improve performance.

Comment: +1; I'll incorporate compiling patterns into my answer at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why Java decided to go in the opposite direction from languages like Perl that has supported regex natively for years. I threw the standard Java regex away and started using my own perl-style regex lib for Java called [MentaRegex](http://mentaregex.soliveirajr.com). See below how regex can make sense in Java.

The method *matches* returns a boolean saying whether we have a regex match or not.

```
matches("Sergio Oliveira Jr.", "/oliveira/i" ) => true
```

The method *match* returns an array with the groups matched. So it not only tells you whether you have a match or not but it also returns the groups matched in case you have a match.

```
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ) => ["11", "22"]
```

The method *sub* allows you perform substitutions with regex.

```
sub("aa11bb22", "s/\\d+/00/g" ) => "aa00bb00"
```

Support global and case-insensitive regex.

```
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/" ) => ["11"]
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ) => ["11", "22"]
matches("Sergio Oliveira Jr.", "/oliveira/" ) => false
matches("Sergio Oliveira Jr.", "/oliveira/i" ) => true
```

Allows you to change the escape character in case you don't like to see so many '\'.

```
match("aa11bb22", "/(\\d+)/g" ) => ["11", "22"]
match("aa11bb22", "/(#d+)/g", '#' ) => ["11", "22"]
```