# regex double white space separation problem

Tags: regex

I want a regex to match words that are delimited by double or more space characters, e.g.

```
ABC  DE  FGHIJ   KLM    NO  P  QRST
```

Notice double or more spaces between the alphabets. Writing regex for such a problem is easy as I only need the first 4 words, as we may search for a word by using `\S+` or `\S+?`

However, for my problem, only 1 white space CAN occur in a word, for example

```
AB C  DE  FG HIJ   KLM    NO  P  QRST
```

Here AB C is a word and FG HIJ is a word as well. In short we want to isolate characters that are spearated by double or more white spaces, I tried using this regex,

```
.+?  +.+?  +.+?  +.+?  +
```

it matches very swiftly, but it takes too much time for strings it doesn't match. (4 matches are given as an example here, in practice I need to match more).

I am in a need of a better regex to accomplish this, so that all the backtracking can be avoided. `[^ ]*` is a regex which will match uptill a space is encountered. Can't we specify a negated character set where we continue matching in case of a single space and break when 2 are encountered? I've tried using positive lookahead but failed miserably.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Saad

Comment: it sounds like you don't need a regexp but just need to split the string based on separator `"  "`. (<--- that's two spaces)

Comment: I need to specify the regex in a developed/compiled system, it just accepts a regex string, it doesn't allow any coding or splitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to split on `\s{2,}` to get the "words" you want, but if you insist on scanning for the tokens, then where as before you have `\S+`, what you have now is `\S+(\s\S+)*`. That's exactly what it says: `\S+`, followed by zero or more `(\s\S+)`. You can use non-capturing group for performance, i.e. `\S+(?:\s\S+)*`. You can even make each repetition possessive if your flavor supports it for extra boost, i.e. `\S++(?:\s\S++)*+`.

Here's a Java snippet to demonstrate:

```
    String text = "AB C  DE  FG HIJ   KLM    NO  P  QRST";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\S++(?:\\s\\S++)*+").matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("[" + m.group() + "]");
    }
```

This prints:

```
[AB C]
[DE]
[FG HIJ]
[KLM]
[NO]
[P]
[QRST]
```

You can of course substitute just the space character instead of `\s` if that's your requirement.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), [Possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

Comment: FWIW, `.+?  +.+?  +.+?  +.+?  +` backtracks catastrophically, http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html ; Don't abuse `.` like this.

Comment: polygenelubricants, thanks for the response. I always knew that was an abuse of . but I was not finding a better soln. Your soln is way better because it specifies the pattern with much more detail. Thanks.

Comment: I was just wondering if we need to allow 2 spaces in our WORDS and delimit with 3 or more spaces the regex would be \S+?(\s{1,2}\S+?)*?
Also, if I need to delimit with a combination of letters for example **poly**, what would be the regex .*?poly offers same backtracking. Any comments polygenelubricants.

Comment: @Saad: to allow up to 2 spaces in the "words", yes, just use `\s{1,2}` instead of simply `\s`. However, all the reluctant modifier in your comment is not necessary, since the pattern is so specific that there's only one way to match anyway. I don't really understand your comment, but you may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532

Answer (score 1):

if you know what the delimiter is (\s\s+), you could **split** instead of **match**.
Simply split on two or more spaces.

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 1):

What about using this pattern:

```
\s{2,}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is even more simple to match 2 or more whitespaces:

> \s{2,}

In PHP the split would look like this

> $list = preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like \s\s+ (one whitespace character, then one or more whitespace characters)?

Edit: it strikes me that whatever language/toolkit you're using may not support "splitting" a string using a regex directly. In that case, you may want to implement that functionality, and instead of attempting to match the *WORDS* in the input, match the *SPACES*, and use the information from those matches (position, length) to extract the words between the matches. In some languages (.NET, others) this functionality is built-in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match all the words (allowing one space in a row), try `\S+(?:[ ]\S+)*` (the character class isn't necessary and can just be a space character, but I included it for clarity). It specifies that at least one non-whitespace character is required, and a space cannot be followed by another one.

You didn't mention what language you're using, but here's an example in PHP:

```
$string = "AB C  DE  FG HIJ   KLM    NO  P  QRST";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\S+(?:[ ]\S+)*/', $string, $matches);
// $matches will contain 'AB C', 'DE', 'FG HIJ', 'KLM', 'NO', 'P', 'QRST'
```

If the requirements are at most one space per word, just change the `*` at the end to a `?`: `\S+(?:[ ]\S+)?`.