# PHP Regex for splitting a string at the first occurrence of a character

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This may be a lame question but I am a total novice with regular expressions. I have some text data in the format:

> *Company Name: Name of the company, place.
>   Company Address: Some,
>   address, here. 
>  Link:
>   http://www.somelink.com*

Now, I want to use a regex to split these into an array of name : value pairs. The regular expression I am trying is `/(.*):(.*)/` with `preg_match_all()` and it does work well with the first two lines but on the third line it returns "Link: http:" in one part and "//www.somelink.com" in other.

**So, is there any way to split the line only at the first occurrence of the character ':'?**

Comment: Why not just use `explode()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: ... and why `preg_match_all()`? Why not just `preg_match`?

Comment: i want to do this in one step that's why :) have been using explode all the time.

Comment: well preg_match_all() is reading multiple lines... preg_match is only returning the first pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like `/(.*?):(.*)/`. The `?` after the `*` will make it "non-greedy", so it will consume as little text as possible that way. I think that will work for your situation. By default, `*` is "greedy", and tries to match as many repetitions as it can.

Edit: See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for more about matching repetition using the `*` and `+` operators.

Answer (score 1):

Use negated character class ([see on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/zGx1PwbVMQ)):

```
/^([^:]*):(.*)$/m
```

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

The `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the pattern are the beginning and end of the line [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). The `m` modifiers turns on the [multi-line mode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html).

The problem with your original pattern is that you're (ab)using `.` when you could've been a lot more specific, and since `*` is greedy, the first group overmatched. It's tempting to try to "fix" that by making the repetition reluctant, but it's *MUCH* better to be more specific and say that the first group is matching anything but `:`.

Note however that this is a *matching* pattern, with captures. It's not actually a *splitting* pattern that matches only the delimiter. The delimiter pattern really is just `:`.

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)

---

#### PHP snippet

Given this:

```
$text = <<<EOT
Company Name: Name of the company, place.
Company Address: Some, address, here.
Link: http://www.somelink.com
EOT;

preg_match_all('/^([^:]*):(.*)$/m', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

The output is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ULzGF)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Company Name: Name of the company, place.
            [1] => Company Name
            [2] =>  Name of the company, place.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Company Address: Some, address, here.
            [1] => Company Address
            [2] =>  Some, address, here.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Link: http://www.somelink.com
            [1] => Link
            [2] =>  http://www.somelink.com
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply... it works but gives me a lot of empty characters before the string, the previous one working fine.

Comment: @aadravid: Check out latest revision. I think I finally figured out your exact requirements.

Comment: +1 Having had a chance to look at this again, I actually agree that this latest revision is probably a better/safer regexp. I just didn't think to do this at the time.

Comment: thanks polygenelubricants, that really seems better than the first one. but i have already implemented eldarerathis solution. but will keep yours in mind in the future :)