# How to extract the code blocks between multiple script tags with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following **function** which pulls in a **Javascript block** via AJAX from a URI and **executes** it:

```
function loadViewViaAjax(url, callbackOnSuccess) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        success: function(objServerResponse) {
            var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
            var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
            while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                eval.call(window,scripts[1]);
            }
            if(typeof callbackOnSuccess != 'undefined') {
                callbackOnSuccess.call();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For example, it pulls in this text, and executes **eveything between the SCRIPT tags**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    clearExtjsComponent(targetRegion);
    var start_info_panel = new Ext.Panel({
        padding: 10,
        style: "margin: 10px",
        width: 300,
        html: '<h1>Html Item 1</h1>'
    });
    replaceComponentContent(targetRegion, start_info_panel);
</script>
```

How can I change the loadViewViaAjax function so that it executes **everything between multiple script tags**?, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    clearExtjsComponent(targetRegion);
    var start_info_panel = new Ext.Panel({
        padding: 10,
        style: "margin: 10px",
        width: 300,
        html: '<h1>Html Item 1</h1>'
    });
    replaceComponentContent(targetRegion, start_info_panel);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    clearExtjsComponent(targetRegion_help);
    var help_panel = new Ext.Panel({
        padding: 10,
        style: "margin: 10px",
        width: 300,
        html: '<p>This is the help text.</p>'
    });
    replaceComponentContent(targetRegion_help, help_panel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly, this is a classic use of a lazy quantifier:

```
/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)<\/script>/gi
```

See also: [What is the difference between .*? and .* regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

Comment: that's what I call answering a question with a question mark, worked perfectly! thanks

Comment: just be careful, this regexp will find a close tag even if it's inside a js string. e.g. `var foo = '</script>';`. Giving you wrong results.

Comment: @Tralamazza - That is true, but real browsers fail that test as well: http://jsbin.com/eyejaf/1 - that is why you should do `var foo = '<' + '/script>';`, for example.

Comment: maybe `<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+?)[^'"]<\/script>` works

Comment: @Tralamazza - That will work for the exact case you've mentioned, but what about `"a </script>"`, or `// </script>`? You can't get around it with a simple regex, you'd need a full parser...

Comment: @Kobi Yup sure, this needs context and so on. I'm not advocating regexp use btw.

Comment: [Digging a bit more](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#notes-specifying-data) I've found that ```/(<script>|<script [^>]*>)([\s\S]+?)<\/[a-zA-Z]/gi``` yields better results. i.e.: ```<scriptt>``` should not match and according to the spec, any ETAGO followed by a [a-zA-Z] closes the block.