# Regex: Match String From Word to Word

Tags: regex

I want to extract a string from a piece of text. This string must start end end with a certain string.

Example:

Word 1 = "Hello"
Word 2 = "World"

Text:

```
Hello, this is a sentence.
The whole World can read this.
What World?
```

The piece of text i want to extract is:

```
Hello, this is a sentence.
The whole World
```

What kind of regular exception should i use for extraction of the string.

Note: the string 'World' occurs twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^\bHello\b.*?\bWorld\b
```

Where the "." also matches newline! Note the word boundaries **\b**, you don't want to match anything which is not exactly Hello or World, as if those words were part of other words.

```
if ($subject =~ m/^\bHello\b.*?\bWorld\b/s) {
    $result = $&;
}
```

Note the s modified which instructs

> **.**

to match newline characters too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is using a [lazy quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130) (`*?`). The would match from the first Hello to the first World. (remember the `/s` flag, for dot-all)

```
Hello.*?World
```

This can be a problem if you don't want the capture text to contain `Hello` either. A more sneaky option then is:

```
Hello(?:(?!Hello|World).)*World
```

Or

```
Hello(?:(?!Hello).)*?World
```

Comment: This will also match anything where Hello is part of a larger context. Same applies with World.