# Regex: matching up to the first occurrence of a word

Tags: regex

What is wrong with :

```
/(?<={).+(?=public)/s
```

full text

```
class WeightConvertor {

private:
    double gram;
    double Kilogram;
    double Tonnes;
    void SetGram(double);
    void SetKiloGram(double);
    void SetTonnes(double);
matching end

public:
    WeightConvertor();
    WeightConvertor(double, double, double);
    ~WeightConvertor();
    void SetWeight(double, double, double);
    void GetWeight(double&, double& ,double&);
    void PrintWeight();
    double TotalWeightInGram();

public:

};
```

how can i match only this text :

```
private:
    double gram;
    double Kilogram;
    double Tonnes;
    void SetGram(double);
    void SetKiloGram(double);
    void SetTonnes(double);
matching end
```

Answer (score 17):

You want a lazy match:

```
/(?<={).+?(?=public)/s
```

See also: [What is the difference between .*? and .* regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)
(which I also answered, as it seems)

Answer (score 1):

You need the "dot matches newline" switch turned on, and a non-greedy (`.*?`) match:

```
(?s)(?<={).+?(?=public)
```

Quoting from the [regex bible](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html), the `(?s)` switch means:

> Turn on "dot matches newline" for the remainder of the regular expression.

*Note that the slashes around your regex have nothing to do with regex - that's a language thing (perl, javascript, etc) and irrelevant to the actual question*

Comment: The op already has the `/s` flag, I think the problem is that the pattern matches until the *last* `public` and not the first.

Comment: @Kobi Thanks I didn't know that was a switch. I know regex but not perl (I assume)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
(?s)(?<={).+?(?=public)
```

its like the answer posted by Bohemian but its lazy, so it matches what you want.