# difference between two regex

Tags: regex

I have two regex:

```
«(\w+\.)+?»
```

and

```
«(\w+\.)+»
```

I think the first one will try to find the minimum of pattern, but
for the next one, I don't know.

Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between .*? and .* for regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

Answer (score 4):

It's called 'greedy' versus 'non-greedy', there's a good overview [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Consider something simpler:

```
.+?\s
```

If the text is this sentence, the first example will match "If ", because the "?" modifier has it looking for the smallest possible match.

```
.+\s
```

If this sentence is being matched by the second example, the entire sentence will be returned (up to the .), as it's the largest match .

Comment: i tried from this page: http://myregexp.com/ for: a.b.c.d.e         with the both regex i wrote, they don't seem to have a difference

Comment: They are different: http://rubular.com/r/amtrupqzsA versus http://rubular.com/r/HQ5DZlgtRN

Comment: for the first one, there are 4 match group and for the other one, there are only one group match

Comment: Here's one more example: http://rubular.com/r/xqIRBk9DU0 verus http://rubular.com/r/c4Ag70gqbh

Answer (score 1):

This is en example of a greedy vs non-greedy regular expression. 
(It's are covered here in the java docs)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html