# Difference in laziness of lookahead assertions between JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm confused by a difference I found between the way JavaScript and PHP handle the following regex.

In JavaScript,

```
'foobar'.replace(/(?=(bar))/     , '$1');
'foobar'.replace(/(?=(bar))?/    , '$1');
'foobar'.replace(/(?:(?=(bar)))?/, '$1');
```

results in, respectively,

```
foobarbar
foobar
foobar
```

as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acheong87/qKb4b/).

However, in PHP,

```
echo preg_replace('/(?=(bar))/', '$1', "foobar<br/>");
echo preg_replace('/(?=(bar))?/', '$1', "foobar<br/>");
echo preg_replace('/(?:(?=(bar)))?/', '$1', "foobar<br/>");
```

results in,

```
foobarbar

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 9 in /homepages/26/d94605010/htdocs/lz/writecodeonline.com/php/index.php(201) : eval()'d code on line 2
foobarbar
```

I'm not so much worried about the warning. But it appears that in JavaScript, lookahead assertions are somehow "lazier" than in PHP. Why the difference? Is this a bug in one of the engines? Which is theoretically more "correct"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real difference is actually very simple:

In JavaScript, `replace` **will only replace the first match**, unless using the `/g` flag (global).
In PHP, `preg_replace` replaces all matches.

The third pattern, `(?:(?=(bar)))?`, can match the empty string in every position, and captures `"bar"` in *some* positions. Without the `/g` flag, it only matches once, at the beginning of the string.

You would have easily seen the difference had you used a more visible replacement string, like `[$1]`.

PHP Example: http://ideone.com/8Mjg6
JavaScript Example, no `/g`: http://jsfiddle.net/qKb4b/3/
JavaScript Example, with `/g`: http://jsfiddle.net/qKb4b/2/

I would also note that ["laziness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532) is a different concept in regular expressions, not related to this question.

Comment: I guess my research was utterly wrong. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thanks Kobi, and sorry for the late acceptance. I haven't had a chance to go back and study it further. I will eventually and report back.