# Regular expression not working when sequence changed

Tags: regex

I have wrote following RegEx to detect all ocurrences of `C. 1909`:

```
input: C. 1909 test C.1909

\b[Cc][\.]\s*?\d+\b
```

this works fine,
However when I try to detect all ocurrences of `1909 C.` using following regex, it does not match anything:

```
input: 1909C. test 1909 C.

\b\d+\s*?[Cc][\.]\b
```

Comment: `\s*?` what are you trying here? `\s*` means "space/tab repeated 0 or more times" and `?` means "repeated 0 or 1 times".

Comment: If you want 4 digits, use `\d{4}`. Replace `x*?` with `x*` where `x` is any regular expression.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - That's a ["lazy" quantifier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3075130/7586) - it isn't wrong, but it is useless in this context.

Comment: @h2ooooooo That means "non-greedy matching" (that is, match as less as possible). Default behavior for * is greedy matching. This is probably due to some requirements not included in the question (I hope...).

Comment: @h2ooooooo: `\s*?` It can be separated by `0 or more spaces`, @Ingo: `\d+` It can contain `1 or more digits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is not a word character, so `\b` after it would only match if it's followed by a word character. Instead of the last `\b` you could use `(?!\w)`, `(?!\S)`, `\B`, or even remove it if you aren't picky.

Comment: @Ingo, true, depending on his specs. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

remove the boundary condition '\b' it will work.