# Regex matches won't separate

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, forms

I'm trying to find a form in HTML using Regex in Visual Basic .NET, though, there are different forms, and I want the one with certain attributes on it.

I want to find this one:

```
    <form method="post"
```

While there are others looking like this:

```
    <form method="get"
```

I already have the code for this, but my code cannot recognize where the first form ends and the next one starts, so I get this whole HTML script where the first form starts

```
    <form>
```

And the last form ends

```
    </form>
```

To understand better what I mean, check this out: http://rubular.com/r/HDU0yVFtIk

Comment: Just use an ungreedy pattern by adding `?` : `<form.*?>[^*]*?<\/form>`. Note that this won't detect *nested* tags. You may use a proper html parser, I read somewhere on SO "HTML Agility pack" or something like that.

Comment: [greedy vs non-greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532) great explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to find the form with the post method?

If so, you're almost there.

```
<form method="post".*>[^*]*<\/form>
```

http://rubular.com/r/DAi75yjQqU

Comment: Though if there are more than one <form method="post" how would I go about then?

Comment: @user2230481 Have you looked into the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.aspx) class in .Net? More specifically, the [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx) and [Regex.IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your last `*` match non-greedy by appending a `?` as in:

```
<form.*>[^*]*?<\/form>
```

per http://rubular.com/r/6cYBTxX85F