# Regex extract part of a link (php)

Tags: php, regex

I got some link like:

```
/3/topic/video1148288/
```

and I want to take the number after video. I can't replace the link with only numbers because there are more before the actual video's id.

I tried

```
$embed = preg_match("#\b/video([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/#", $raw);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. It works and here's a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT2uE1). However I would replace all those numbers with `[0-9]+` which means match a digit one or more times. If you are certain that there will always be 7 numbers, then you could use `[0-9]{7}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$raw = "/3/topic/video1148288/";
preg_match("#/video(\d+)/#", $raw, $matches);
$embed = $matches[1];
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/oLPMX

One thing to note from looking at your attempt, is that `preg_match` returns a truthy/falsely value, not the actual matches. Those are found in the third param (`$matches` in my example).

Answer (score 1):

```
$raw = "/3/topic/video1148288/";

preg_match("/video(\d+)/", $raw, $results);

print "$results[1]";
```

Comment: What if the link was `/3/topic/video1148288/foo`? `.*` is not a very good idea, IMO.

Comment: Read [the difference between greedy and non-greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/(?<=video)\d+/i', $raw, $match);
echo $match[0];
```