# Remove part of string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can i replace unused section in content. For example:

```
$content = "
    Test content

    [section]
        Section Content
    [section]

    End.
";

$content = preg_replace('/\[section\](.*)\[section\]/', '', $content);
```

Thanks

Comment: add the `s` modifier to match newlines with `.`. Also don't forget to make your expression [ungreedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex) `/\[section\](.*?)\[section\]/s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`s`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier allows a dot  metacharacter in the pattern to match all characters, including newlines.

The [`i`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier is used for case-insensitive matching allowing both upper and lower case letters. By adding the quantifier `?` it makes for a **non greedy** match and matches the least amount possible.

```
$content = preg_replace('/\[section\].*?\[section\]/si', '', $content);
```

See [`Demo`](https://eval.in/72842)

Comment: @adoweb If this worked, its nice to accept an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2):

What's the regex for? This should work and will run a lot quicker:

```
$content = explode('[section]',$content);
$content = $content[0].$content[2];
```