# Difference in results between Java matches vs JavaScript match

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I was brushing up on my regular expressions in java when I did a simple test

```
Pattern.matches("q", "Iraq"); //false
"Iraq".matches("q"); //false
```

But in JavaScript

```
/q/.test("Iraq"); //true
"Iraq".match("q"); //["q"] (which is truthy)
```

What is going on here? And can I make my java regex pattern "q" behave the same as JavaScript?

Comment: Please don't compare methods from two different languages merely based on their names. Rather go, and look into the respective documentation.

Comment: I figured out that it matches the entire string, but java did not have any documentation besides "For a more precise description of the behavior of regular expression constructs, please see Mastering Regular Expressions, 3nd Edition, Jeffrey E. F. Friedl, O'Reilly and Associates, 2006."

Comment: The sentence you quote is preceded by no less than 9 screenfuls of detailed elaboration of the Java regex syntax and semantics.

Comment: And, of course, that's just the class documentation, where the documentation for the particular method you call points to this: [`Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())

Comment: Ok i found it not on Pattern, but on (obviously) Matcher's page - The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern...

Comment: And on the `Pattern` page you should have found this: `behaves in exactly the same way as the expression
 Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input).matches()`, which makes it indeed obvious.

Comment: Yea the point is i read all (9 screens) of the documentation for the class with the method I was using, but couldn't find it.  But now I did (on the docs for another resource) thanks which is why i asked on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript `match` returns substrings which matches used regex. In Java `matches` checks if entire string matches regex.

If you want to find substrings that match regex use Pattern and Matcher classes like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourData);
while(m.find()){
   m.group();//this will return current match in each iteration
   //you can also use other groups here using their indexes
   m.group(2);
   //or names (?<groupName>...)
   m.group("groupName");
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. A way around the default `matches` behavior.

Comment: @jermel and Michael Perrenoud: glad you like it :)

Answer (score 5):

This is because in Java `Pattern#matches` OR `String#matches` expects you to match complete input string not just a part of it.

On the other hand Javascript's `String#match` can match input partially as you're also seeing in your examples.

Comment: And if I understand it correctly, it's just a different engine - period. They work differently between Java, Ruby, JavaScript, Python, .NET, and so on - right?

Comment: Yes that is true. Java's `matches` name for this method causes lot of confusion also.

Comment: Is there a *switch* in Java though that can keep it from being prefixed and suffixed with the start and end characters?

Comment: And Javascript `match` method returns an array containing all the matched groups for that regex pattern, starting with group 0.

Comment: btw.: Python also has `re.match()` and `re.search()`. The first one _match_es the whole string from beginning to end and the second one _search_es through it if it finds the string

Comment: In Java it needs to be done like this: `Pattern.matches(".*?q.*", "Iraq");` OR better to use `Pattern#find()` method which is there for partial matches.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, `String.match` looks for a partial match. In Java, `Pattern.matches` returns `true` if the whole input string is matched by the given pattern. That is equivalent to say, in your example, that "iraq" should match `^q$`, which it obvious doesn't.

Here it is from [Java's Matcher Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) (note that `Pattern.matches` internally creates a `Matcher` then calls `matches` on it):

> `public boolean matches()`
>
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern. If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.
>
> Returns: true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

If you want to test for only a part of the string, add `.*?` at the beginning of the regex, and `.*` at the end, such as `Pattern.match("iraq", ".*?q.*")`.

Note that `.*q.*` would also work, but using the reluctant operator in front might significantly improve performances if the input string is very long. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532/2887657) for explanation on the difference between reluctant and greedy operators, and their effects on backtracking for explanation.

Comment: :-) That quote is from Matcher's javadoc

Comment: @jermel Indeed it is. Fixed.