# JavaScript Regular expression text parsing

Tags: regex, text-parsing

I have a string like the following

```
~~<b>A<i>C</i></b>~~/~~<u>D</u><b>B</b>~~has done this.
```

I am trying to get the text inside <b> tag. I am trying

```
<b>(.+)</b>
```

But I am getting `<b>A<i>C</i></b>~~/~~<u>D</u><b>B</b>`, but I need `<b>A<i>C</i></b>` as first match and `<b>B</b>` as the second match

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you post the regular expression that you've already tried?...

Comment: Thou shall not try to parse html with regular expressions. Seriously, in most cases you will end up with a pile of unmaintainable and error-prone code - just imagine Nested sections of interest (eG. <b>...<i>...<b>...</b>...</i>...</b>). Make sure that you have a **very** compelling reason to choose this path.

Comment: The following questions in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) may be of interest: [In-depth discussion on the differences between greedy versus non-greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532) (listed under "Quantifiers"), and [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) (under "General Information"). Please consider bookmarking the FAQ for future reference.

Comment: This parsing will be under HTML5 canvas where I have to parse and create canvas text. I am doing this because I can not use html text inside canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
<b>(.+?)</b>
```

This will ensure that the match stops at the first `</b>` it finds.

However, I would generally recommend using a proper XML or HTML parser for this sort of thing. Regular expressions are simply not powerful enough to handle the recursive structure of XML.

Comment: As soon as`<b>` gets any attributes, this fails.

Comment: @JanDvorak true, and that's why I recommend using a proper parser.