# preg to extract from h1 tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this content:

```
<h1 class="contf _48_black caphead">
    <span>The essence of social media is knowing your audience and engaging them in something they love. In real-time, relevance and resonance!&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
        <img class="retwt" src="images/retweet.svg">
    </a>
    <span class="secmov"><img src="images/arrow.svg"></span>
</h1>
```

I am trying to extract the content from the h1 TAG as follows but not able to get it.

```
<?php
$result = <h1 class="contf _48_black caphead">
        <span>The essence of social media is knowing your audience and engaging them in something they love. In real-time, relevance and resonance!&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
            <img class="retwt" src="images/retweet.svg">
        </a>
        <span class="secmov"><img src="images/arrow.svg"></span>
    </h1>;

preg_match_all('$<h1(.*?)</h1>$i',$result, $subresult);
print_r($subresult);

?>
```

where as the following works-

```
preg_match_all('$span>(.*?)</span>$i',$result, $subresult);
```

Can some one please let me.

Comment: Use DOMDocument for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Agreed, don't parse HTML with `preg_match`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the `reg_exp` what i used below. I hope this what exactly you are looking for.

```
preg_match_all('/<h1.*?>(.*)<\/h1>/msi',$result, $subresult);
print_r($subresult);
```

Comment: Using `.*?` and `.*` in the same expression with `U` is not only confusing but also misleading. I don't recommend the `U` modifier at all.

Comment: Ok i have removed U :P

Comment: It seems you might need to read [the difference between greedy and ungreedy/lazy quantifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532).

Comment: Thanks it worked. Only Modification I did was preg_match_all('/<h1.*?>(.*?)<\/h1>/msi',$result, $subresult);
Because when there were multiple h1 tags the results were all clubbed together..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the m-option to make the dot match newlines.

```
preg_match_all('`<h1(.*?)</h1>`im',$result, $subresult);
```

But I agree with the comments that you should use DOMDocument instead.

Comment: I won't use `$` as delimiter since it has a meaning in regex which might confuse further readers...

Comment: @HamZa you are right. Usually I do not use them either. I was just lazy when copying the code.