# How to parse string with regex with [i] inside string

Tags: c#, regex

I have expression like this

```
 R403[i] == 3 and R404[i] == 2 AND R405[i] == 1 and R403[i+1] == 5 and R404[i+1] == 2 AND R405[i+1] == 1 R231[2]
```

And I want get all occurence of my expression using this regex

```
[R|M|B].*?\]
```

But one condition again that I want to apply it must contains variable `i` inside so `R121[1]` would not be capture.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Hint `[R|M|B]` is the same as `[BMR|]`. Read about how [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly this would be the regex:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[RMB]\d{3}\[.*?i.*?\]");
```

If your "i" less expressions can come before the ones with an i use instead:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[RMB]\d{3}\[[^]]*?i[^]]*?\]");
```

Comment: thanks.. could you give me explanation about `\[.*?i.*?\]` I'm still confuse about this regex

Comment: simple: the squared brackets have to contain an i at some point .*? means all characters are allowed or no characters but as few as possible

Comment: so this should match R333[1+i] as well as R344[i+1] and R333[i]

Comment: This is a special case because its after the * . see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex for explaination

Comment: Added better regex so that the order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It will check for group match of the pattern.

```
 string pattern = @"[RMB]\d{3}\[\d*\]";
 string input = " M403[50] == 3 and R404[i] == 2 AND R405[i] == 1 and R403[i+1] == 5 and R404[i+1] == 2 AND R405[i+1] == 1 R231[2]";

 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Mactch:        {0}", match.Value);
      Console.WriteLine();
  }
```

Comment: [R|M|B] would capture the | as a literal. and he wants all that contain i not those without