# PHP preg_replace with groups of numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group

Alright here is what I have

`$string=Something something 1234-123'; //can be an arbitrary amount of digits on each side of hyphen
$numbers=preg_replace("/.*([0-9]*-[0-9]*).*/","$1", $string);
echo $numbers;`

This is printing out just "-123", it should be printing out 1234-123. I feel like i'm just missing something really simple here.

Comment: i tested this out on regex101.com with the expression: ([0-9]*-[0-9]*) and with the test string: Something something 1234-123, the result was that i got: 1234-123

Comment: `"/.*([0-9]+?-[0-9]+?).*/"`

Comment: If you only want to **extract** 1234-123 don't use `preg_replace`, use **`preg_match`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be more [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532) I guess

`.*?([0-9]*-[0-9]*).*`

Comment: will do, i have to wait 10 more minutes to do so.

Comment: sorry, got confused in a hurry. Thanks for pointing out @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 0):

I'd use preg_match instead:

```
$string = 'Something something 1234-123';
preg_match('/\d+-\d+/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0],"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
1234-123
```