# wildcard search using replace function

Tags: java, search, wildcard

I tried to implement wildcards search in my application using some algorithms (k-gram algorithm etc.), but it was very complex.

Until i found this code, and it works perfectly .. but i don't know how it get check and get results !

Code:

```
public static boolean wildCardMatch(String text, String pattern)
{
  return text.matches( pattern.replace("?", ".?").replace("*", ".*?") );
}
```

Does their anyone help me to knows how it work ? what's the idea of replace function?

Comment: It is using regex...

Comment: I know, but could you show it with small example ?

Comment: The replace function is taking the user input `*` and converting it to what regex understands `.*?` which is match anything non-greedy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're speaking about is called the **[glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)**.

In the Java world, the glob pattern is more often translated into a regex pattern.

In your scenario, the implementation is very basic: the `replace` method is used to replace all occurrences of `?` into the regex equivalent `.?`. Then all occurences of `*` are replaced by `.*?`.

So if you have the following glob pattern: `abc*.def`, the regex will become `abc.*?.def`.

When the regex is finally ready, it is used to be checked against the variable `text` using the method `matches`. This latter method accepts a regex as input.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using is [`String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

It takes two objects implementing `CharSequence` interface as parameters, which might be one of following:

- `CharBuffer`
- `Segment`
- #### `String`
- `StringBuffer`
- `StringBuilder`

And replaces every occurence of first `CharSequence` with second `CharSequence` in a `String`.

---

In your case, if the `pattern` parameter would contain `**??`, the `text.matches` method would get `.?.?.*?.*?` as the input, and that's what the `text` parameter must've contain as well (in terms of [regular expressions](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)), in order to successfully match them and the method to return `true`.

**To clarify:**

[Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

Comment: if the text is yellow ,  and pattern is yel* .. it will take all chars before * in pattern and check if it could be replaced in text ?? or it it has the same in text and return true ?

Comment: If the pattern is `yel*`, it will be turned into `yel.*` by `replace` method, which will match `yellow`, as `.*` means `Any character, occuring 0 or more times`.
Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/