# How to remove strings from in between brackets with regex...python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

I need to pull out a single string containing the words from extracted fields:

```
[[cat]][[dog]][[mouse]][[apple]][[banana]][[pear]][[plum]][[pool]]
```

So from this I need: `cat dog mouse apple banana pear plum pool`.

I've been trying for 2 hours to make a regular expression for this.

The best I get is `(?<=[[]\S)(.*)(?=]])` 
which gets me:

```
cat]][[dog]][[mouse]][[apple]][[banana]][[pear]][[plum]][[pool
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: A simple search for characters would do. `/[a-z]+/g`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX0hA0/1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between .\*? and .\* for regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)

Comment: can the double brackets be nested?

Comment: This really looks like an XY problem where you've created some badly formed data and now need to get at the information. Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `re.finditer`. Let your string be `s`.
This assumes there can be anything in between [[ and ]]. Otherwise, the comment by @noob applies.

```
>>> [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer('\[\[(.*?)\]\]', s)]
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'plum', 'pool']
```

Alternatively, with lookarounds and `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.findall('(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])', s)
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'plum', 'pool']
```

For large strings, the `finditer` version seemed to be slightly faster when I timed the alternatives.

```
In [5]: s=s*1000
In [6]: timeit [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer('\[\[(.*?)\]\]', s)]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.61 ms per loop
In [7]: timeit re.findall('(?<=\[\[).*?(?=\]\])', s)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.93 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

simple [**`re.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) will work:

```
>>> s = '[[cat]][[dog]][[mouse]][[apple]][[banana]][[pear]][[plum]][[pool]]'
>>> import re
>>> print re.split(r'[\[\]]{2,4}', s)[1:-1]
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'plum', 'pool']
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do it with a regular expression?

```
extract = "[[cat]][[dog]][[mouse]][[apple]][[banana]][[pear]][[plum]][[pool]]"
word_list = [word for word in extract.replace('[', '').split(']') if word != '']
print word_list
```

Output:

```
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'plum', 'pool']
```

Got it *with* regular expressions now.  SImply find non-empty strings of stuff without brackets.

import re

```
target = "[[cat]][[dog]][[mouse]][[apple]][[banana]][[pear]][[plum]][[pool]]"
word_list = ' '.join(re.findall("[^\[\]]+", target))
print word_list
```

Edited to return the single string, rather than a list of strings.

Comment: No I dont have too. I had been solving a few of my cleaning text issues with them so i just kept trying them. This did work though. Thanks!