# python re expression confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7

When reading book: web scraping with python, the re expression confused me,

> ```
> webpage_regex = re.compile('<a[^>]+href=["\'](.*?)["\']', re.IGNORECASE)
> ```

And a link in usually looks like:

```
<a href="/view/Afghanistan-1">
```

My confusion is that:

1. Since `[^>]` means no `>`, why it followed by a `+`?  This `+` seems useless.
2. The confusion is that `(.*?)` , since `*` means repeat 0 or more times, why it needs `?` to repeat `*` again?

Comment: `[^>]+` means "1 or more characters that are not `>`". `*?` is a non-greedy quantifier - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532

Comment: @khelwood Thanks! `*?` is clear for me now. But is there any difference between "1 characters that are not `>`" and " 1 or more characters that are not `>`" ?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between one and more than one. `"x"` is one character that is not `>`. `"xyz"` is more than one characters that are not `>`.

Comment: [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com). Check your regex explanation here.

Comment: @khelwood  You are right!  Get it

Comment: @Regex101  Thanks! Nice tool

Answer (score 0):

1. `[>]+` matches any other attributes and their corresponding values inside the tag.
2. `*?` matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed. so it will only capture the text that would before the NEXT `["\']`