# Regular expression in Kettle

Tags: regex, kettle

Does anybody know how to find pattern like `^.^` in Kettle (for example, ^44^, ^!^)?

`'.'` represents any letters which can be single or multiple.

I found this pattern, `>.<` (for example, >44!<) through `(.*)(>.*<)(.*)`

So I applied same way as `(.*)(^.*^)(.*)`. But it never finds it.

Actually I do not know the meaning of (.*) exactly also, if anybody knows about it, could you give some advice?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions)

Comment: Yes, now I understand what (.*) however, the first question is not solved yet.  How to find the pattern ^44^ or ^!^?

Comment: Try `[^][^^]*[^]`

Answer (score 1):

You can find pattern like `^44^ or ^|^` by using the following *regex*

```
(\^.*?\^)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vLRSLQ/3)

Comment: Kettle is implemented in Java, so your pattern `(\^.*?\^)` will not work as expected.  Java has its own RE implementation and there are subtle and not so subtle differences in comparison with PCRE, some restrictions imposed by Kettle on top.

Answer (score 0):

This is barely about Kettle.  It's more about regular expressions in Java.  After you have aquired a [basic understanding of RE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), you will want to [lookup the pattern constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) time and again.