# Regex.Matches Fails To Find Multiple Matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have run into a problem when trying to find multiple matches in a length of text. The text has the following format:

```
string text = "#IDENTIFIER http://www.link1.com #IDENTIFIER http://www.link2.org #IDENTIFIER http://www.link3.com #IDENTIFIER http://www.link4.net";
```

My objective is to extract each *#IDENTIFIER link* occurrence from this and I am doing it using the following code:

```
string pat = @"(#IDENTIFIER)(.*)\.(com|org|net)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pat);
foreach(Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", match.Value, match.Index);
}
```

The problem is, it returns one match and not 4. Why are the in-between patterns ignored?

Do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Amazing, Thank you!

Comment: Try `RegexOptions.RightToLeft`. That usually works when handling recurring prefixes.

Comment: @Lloyd is right, but if it's a multiline-problem use the m flag : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's because `.*` on its own is generally greedy. Instead try using `.*?`:

```
string pat = @"(#IDENTIFIER)(.*?)\.(com|org|net)";
```

Comment: I did, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: For an explanation: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075150/3883866