# How to extract text between 2 words in PostgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column criteria which contains below similar text in each of its row:-

```
inclusion : ajjsdijd
sdsjdjs
ieroeito trorg inclusion
sdkjwedk

exclusion :
sdkjwdowek
 ksdldk exclusion
skdkefk
kfkwkfwe
```

I want to extract the text between first inclusion and exclusion occurance. So, here i want result as

```
ajjsdijd
sdsjdjs
ieroeito trorg inclusion
sdkjwedk
```

Also, I want to extract the text after first exclusion keyword:

```
sdkjwdowek
 ksdldk exclusion
skdkefk
kfkwkfwe
```

I am currently using below PostgreSQL but this creates issue and picks text between first inclusion and last exclusion..

```
substring(lower(criteria) from 'inclusion(.+)exclusion')
substring(lower(criteria) from 'exclusion(.+)')
```

Comment: Try using a lazy quantifier instead: `(.+?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE input1 TEXT;
DECLARE output1 TEXT;
DECLARE output2 TEXT;
declare posincl integer;
declare posexcl integer;
BEGIN
  input1 := 'inclusion : ajjsdijd
  sdsjdjs
  ieroeito trorg inclusion
  sdkjwedk

  exclusion :
sdkjwdowek
 ksdldk exclusion
skdkefk
kfkwkfwe' ;
  posincl := position('inclusion :' in input1);
  posexcl := position('exclusion :' in input1);
  output1 := substring(input1 from (posincl + 11) for (posexcl - posincl - 11));  
  output2 := substring(input1 from (posexcl + 11)); 
  RAISE NOTICE 'Value of output1: %', output1;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Value of output2: %', output2;
END $$;
```

Comment: Got me by 10s...

Comment: @MateusA.  And just as I was about to go to bed too ...

Comment: +1 for the whole code and the time. By the way, the text at the top shouldn't be a formatted as a code (`You could try something like this:`)

Comment: @MateusA. Thanks corrected.  Definitely time to switch off!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it happens is that you're using a Greedy quantifier.

> Repetition in regex by default is greedy: they try to match as many reps as possible, and when this doesn't work and they have to backtrack, they try to match one fewer rep at a time, until a match of the whole pattern is found. As a result, when a match finally happens, a greedy repetition would match as many reps as possible. [-polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532/7225971)

What you have to do is change it to a Lazy quantifier, by adding the `?` operator:

```
/inclusion(.+?)exclusion/
```

Try looking at this demo: https://regex101.com/r/TYGBrA/1 (Note the colon in your input with your given regex which could also be ignored with the sequence [`\s*:\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/TYGBrA/2)).