# Extract delimited substrings from a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that looks like this

```
my $source = "PayRate=[[sDate=05Jul2017,Rate=0.05,eDate=06Sep2017]],item1,item2,ReceiveRate=[[sDate=05Sep2017,Rate=0.06]],item3" ;
```

I want to use capture groups to extract only the `PayRate` values contained within the first `[[...]]` block.

```
$1 = "Date=05Jul2017,Rate=0.05,EDate=06Sep2017"
```

I tried this but it returns the entire string.

```
my $match =~ m/PayRate=\[\[(.*)\]\],/ ;
```

It is clear that I have to put specific patterns for the series of `{(.*)=(.*)}` blocks inside. Need expert advice.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a *greedy* match `.*`, which consumes as much input as possible while still matching, you're matching the *first* `[[` to the *last* `]]`.

Instead, use a *reluctant* match `.*?`, which matches as *little* as possible while still matching:

```
my ( $match) = $source =~ /PayRate=\[\[(.*?)\]\]/;
```

Comment: Thank you Bohemian!. I just learned little bit more about greedy vs non-greedy quantifiers. Works like a charm now. Below link explains well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions

Comment: *Reluctant* is not the opposite of *greedy*.

Comment: @Borodin what's your point? (btw I did not state that reluctant is the opposite of greedy, although they are more or less "opposite")

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm saying that *reluctant* is a poor choice to describe a *non-greedy* quantifier (as is *lazy*) and as far as I know it's not commonly used outside Oracle's Java documentation. If I had my way I'd choose *frugal*, but that's even less popular.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [/x modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) on match (and substitute) so you can use white space for easier reading and comments to tell what is going on. Limit the patterns by matching everything not in the pattern. `[^\]]*?` is better than `.*?`.

```
my ( $match ) = $line =~ m{
    Payrate \= \[\[  # select which part
    ( [^\]]*? )      # capture anything between square brackets
}x;
```