# (C#) Regex.Matches to find out minimum-length match string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find matching string that takes minimum length, but my code shows exactly opposite, how can I fixed it?

```
string line = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx A(a,b) and A(a,b) > 0 xxxxxxxxx \n xxxxxxxxx A(a,b) and A(a,b) > 0 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string Pattern = "A.+?>";
MatchCollection M1 = Regex.Matches(line, Pattern);
Console.WriteLine(M1[0].ToString()); //I want 【A(a,b) >】 but it shows 【A(a,b) and A(a,b) >】
Console.WriteLine(M1[1].ToString()); //I want 【A(a,b) >】 but it shows 【A(a,b) and A(a,b) >】
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Try to exclude the string `A(a,b)` from the `.+` using negative lookahead.

Comment: somehow so `A[^A]+?>` ?

Comment: Negative character group would work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern starts at the first `A` it finds, and then matches until the next `>` it finds - but as you saw - there could be another `A` in the middle.
This is explained nicely in the second example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532/7586

The simplest option is to match explicitly what you want instead of `.+`, for example:

```
string Pattern = @"A\(\w+,\w+\)\s*>";
```

[Working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=A%5c%28%5cw%2b%2c%5cw%2b%5c%29%5cs*%3e&i=xxxxxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxx+%5cn+xxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)

As the comments suggested, negative character classes can also work, for example [`A[^A]+>`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=A%5b%5eA%5d%2b%3e&i=xxxxxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxx+%5cn+xxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx), or if that is too limiting, [`A\([^()]+\)\s*>`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=A%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%5c%29%5cs*%3e&i=xxxxxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxx+%5cn+xxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).

Another option that would work in this case to use [`RightToLeft` matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_RightToLeft), like this:

```
MatchCollection M1 = Regex.Matches(line, Pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

`RightToLeft` would start at the `>` sign, and then the lazy quntifier `.+` will behave as you expect - reaching only the first `A` it finds. This has a symmetrical problem, potentially failing for multiple `>`s.
[Working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=A.%2b%3f%3e&i=xxxxxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxx+%5cn+xxxxxxxxx+A%28a%2cb%29+and+A%28a%2cb%29+%3e+0+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&o=r&s=80)

Comment: `RightToLeft` would probably fail on `A(a,b) > >`.

Comment: @user202729 - Good point. It would *definitely* fail for that. I'll add a comment.