# pattern match get lastindex of a character

Tags: java

the below will give me between `_` and `.` for example `Pet_you.txt`
will give me `you`

but if I get `pet_te_you.txt` will get `te_you` but instead I need `you` result. how to fix my pattern to take last `_`?

```
Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\_(.*?)\\.");
Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("pet_te_you.txt");
while (m.find()) {
    Type = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(dbType);
}
```

Comment: Dupe somewhere. Let me find.

Comment: `"_([^_]*)\\."` (not underscore)

Comment: Why use pattern matching when you can use lastIndexOf?

Comment: @antonyh the length character is not fix , if i said last index of _ then i will have you.txt . then how to remove the .txt ?

Comment: [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48395325/5267751).

Comment: Some of the answers such as those by notyou, Anirudh, yudong shen show how this is possible with lastIndexOf. You just have to do lastIndexOf twice (once for the _ and again for the .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a non-regex pattern, you could use `substring` twice - once for the `lastIndexOf("_")` and then for the `lastIndexOf(".")`.

```
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Or a fun alternative to combine them both in a *non-ugly way:

```
s = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1).substring(0, s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_") + 1).lastIndexOf("."));
```

Or perhaps, loop through the `String` in reverse (I used a `StringBuilder`), from `lastIndexOf(".") - 1` until you reach a non-character (or perhaps a `_`).

```
for (int i = s.lastIndexOf(".") - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(i))) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's an [online](https://ideone.com/e9wecG) example.

<sub>*This is definitely ugly</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You just have to avoid "_" in the capture pattern.

```
Pattern.compile("\\_([^_]+?)\\.")
```

Comment: thanks its worled , but is it possible to have the result using lastindexof ?

Answer (score 1):

Same implementation using lastIndexOf

```
String text = "pet_te_you.txt";
System.out.println(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("_")+1, text.lastIndexOf(".")));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can match with look around: `(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)`, and yes, you can have result using `lastIndexOf` too.

```
String as[] = {"pet_te_you.txt", "Pet_you.txt"};
Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\\.)");
for (String s : as) {
    int beginIndex = s.lastIndexOf("_");
    int endIndex = s.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (beginIndex >= 0 && endIndex >= 0 && beginIndex < endIndex) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(beginIndex + 1, endIndex));
    }

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}

output:
    you
    you
    you
    you
```