# Can I remove a substring from a string starting at a known position and ending at a given character?

Tags: string, powershell, replace, substring

I need to extract sections of a string but I won't always know the length/content.

I've tried converting the string to XML or JSON for instance, and can't come up with any other way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Example string:

```
'Other parts of the string Name="SomeRandomAmountOfCharacters" blah blah'
```

What I need to remove always starts with an attribute name and ends with a closing double quote. So can I say I'd like to remove substring starting at Name=" and go until we reach the closing "?

Expected result:

```
'Other parts of the string blah blah'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this

```
$s = 'Other parts of the string Name="SomeRandomAmountOfCharacters" blah blah'
$s -replace ' Name=".*?"'
```

or like this:

```
$s = 'Other parts of the string Name="SomeRandomAmountOfCharacters" blah blah'
$s -replace ' Name="[^"]*"'
```

to avoid unintentionally removing other parts of your string in case it contains multiple attributes or additional double quotes. `.*?` is a non-greedy match for a sequence of any character except newlines, so it'll match up to the next double quote. `[^"]*` is a character class matching the longest consecutive sequence of characters that aren't double-quotes, so it'll also match up to the next double quote.

You'll also want to add the miscellaneous construct `(?ms)` to your expression if you have a multiline string.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. The other answers were great, but you accounted for the possibility of additional attributes.

Comment: I've never seen the pattern `.*?` before. What role does the question mark after the asterisk play?

Comment: Never mind, I found the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good reference: https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html

In your case

```
$s = 'Other parts of the string Name="SomeRandomAmountOfCharacters" blah blah'
$s -replace '\W*Name=".*"\W*', " "
```

or

```
$newString = $s -replace 'W*Name=".*"\W*', " "
```

This will replace your matching string, including the surrounding whitespace, with a single space.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. Brought me very close to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at something like this and understand how it works.

```
$pattern = '(.*)Name=".*" (.*)'
$str = 'Other parts of the string Name="SomeRandomAmountOfCharacters" blah blah'

$ret = $str -match $pattern

$out = $Matches[1]+$Matches[2]

$str
"===>"
$out
```

See also: https://regex101.com/r/wM2xlc/1