# Can i extract some data from HTML file i have downloaded it has some JSON in it

Tags: c#, json, html-agility-pack, read-write

This is the link to the HTML file i have downloaded

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z7A9U0qZSVtLMQDbsVtPyZVz9Zm73-ZQ

from this file at the end you can see some data like this

```
<div data-react-class="packs/v9/phone/containers/AreaCodeListing" data-react-props="{"areaCodes":[{"phone_prefix":"(202) 200","details":["Sprint"],"location":"Washington, DC","href":"/202-200"},{"phone_prefix":"(202) 201","details":["Verizon"],"location":"Washington, DC","href":"/202-201"},{"phone_prefix":"(202) 202","details":["General Service Carrier"],"location":"Washington, DC","href":"/202-202"},{"phone_prefix":"(202) 203","details":["T-Mobile"],"location":"Washington, DC","href":"/202-203"},{"phone_prefix":"(202) 204","details":["XO Communications"],"location":"Washington, DC","href":"/202-204"}
```

From this page how can i extract **href** values ?
I think **JSON** can do the job but i am stuck in how to reach to that point to get that json

Or is there any other best way to get **href** value from this HTML page i have downloaded ?

Comment: You only need href or other properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like [HTLMAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to parse the HTML document and then extract out the JSON as required.

Comment: i had but no response because this div has react class ,

Comment: if you can make a sample code please it will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The file you downloaded is not valid HTML, because it is a React view.
Therefore, tools like HTMLAgilityPack will not be very helpful for you.

You could try to see if you have any luck using headless browsers such as [WebKit.NET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/). You might be able to interject somewhere in the process of building the final HTML.

Apart from that, the only option I can think of is to use regular expressions to get the data you want from the file. For example:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=data-react-props=""){.*}(?=<)");
var match = regex.Match(pageContents);
if (match.Success)
{
    foreach (var gr in match.Groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(gr);
    }
}
```

Comment: its nice but how about instead of matching it with data-react-props= y dont we match it with  **areaCodes** or **href** can you make a regex for this one ? please

Comment: the above one is showing only the first successful match

Answer (score 0):

**First Approach**

If you want whole object of AreaCode try first Approach.

```
public List<AreaCode> GetAllAreaCodes(string htmlString)
{

    List<AreaCode> areraCodes = new List<AreaCode>();

    Regex rgxAttr = new Regex(@"data-react-props=""{(.*?)}""");
    Regex rgxValue = new Regex(@"""{(.*?)}""");


    var attrResult = rgxAttr.Matches(htmlString);
    List<string> attrValues = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in attrResult)
    {
        var val = rgxValue.Match(match.Value);
        attrValues.Add(val.Value.Replace("\"{", "{").Replace("}\"", "}"));
    }

    foreach (var item in attrValues)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var dn = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(item) as Dictionary<string, object>;

        if (dn != null && dn.ContainsKey("areaCodes"))
        { 
            var abc = item.Remove(item.Length - 1, 1).Remove(0, 1).Replace(@"""areaCodes"":", "");
            areraCodes = js.Deserialize<List<AreaCode>>(abc);
        }
    }
    return areraCodes;
}
public class AreaCode
{
    public string phone_prefix { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string[] details { get; set; }

}
```

**Second Approach**

If you need only href value then use second approach.

```
public List<string> GetAllHref(string htmlString)
{

    List<string> hrefList = new List<string>();

    Regex rgxAttr = new Regex(@"data-react-props=""{(.*?)}""");
    Regex rgxValue = new Regex(@"""{(.*?)}""");

    var attrResult = rgxAttr.Matches(htmlString);

    List<string> attrValues = new List<string>();

    foreach (Match match in attrResult)
    {
        var val = rgxValue.Match(match.Value);
        attrValues.Add(val.Value.Replace("\"{", "{").Replace("}\"", "}"));
    }

    dynamic ob = null;
    foreach (var item in attrValues)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dn = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(item) as Dictionary<string, object>;
        if (dn != null && dn.ContainsKey("areaCodes"))
            ob = dn["areaCodes"];
    }

    var s = ob as Array;
    foreach (Dictionary<string, object> item in s)
        hrefList.Add(item["href"].ToString());

    return hrefList;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between .*? and .* in your regular expression?

Comment: @BartvanderDrift for your reference please checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions