# Group various parts of String using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a String as below:

`1. Name (Firstnames), Purpose 01-MAY-2019 14:49 UTC (Accept)remarks are starting now (some random, thing, I am typing, in remarks)`

I want to create a Group index of 6 items as below:

```
1 - 1
2 - Name (Firstnames)
3 - Purpose
4 - 01-MAY-2019 14:49 UTC
5 - Accept
6 - remarks are starting now (some random, thing, I am typing, in remarks)
```

Except the remarks part in the 6th item, the remaining items are always in the given format which I can check with a Matcher. How do I achieve this?

I formulated the below regex but it still fails for some statements as the one given above:

```
(\d+)\.(.*),([^0-9]*)(.*)\((.*)\)(.*)
```

Comment: Regex is greedy by default. Your 4th group `.*\(` will go to the last occurence of `(` and not to the first. That's why your (Accept) will be skipped. Change those to lazy:
`(\d+)\.(.*),([^0-9]*)(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*)`

Comment: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add lazy quantifiers for that group.

`(\d+)\.(.*?),([^0-9]*)(.*?)\((.*?)\)(.*)`

Read more about lazy and greedy quantifiers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532

Comment: You should point what is a "lazy quantifier" to highlight what you have changed. Good answer but not really visible.

Comment: Agreed. Added a reference answer.