# Python regex to remove text between some pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have text in following format.

> **|start|** this is first para to remove **|end|**.
>   this is another text.
>   **|start|** this is another para to remove **|end|**. Again some free text

I want to remove all text in between |start| and |end|

I have tried following re.

```
regex = '(?<=\|start\|).+(?=\|end\|)'
re.sub(regex, ''. text)
```

It returns

> "Again some free text"

But I expect to return

> this is another text. Again some free text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions/3075532#3075532

Comment: Note the start/end delimiters are in lookaround constructs in your pattern and thus will remain in the resulting string after `re.sub`. Try `r'(?s)\|start\|.*?\|end\|\W*'`. Do you also need to remove all newlines? Then, you need to add `.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: The regex specified in @WiktorStribiżew comment should work just fine. I've just tested it in https://regex101.com/ .

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. No I do not need to remove newlines.

Comment: @Hima Ok, but probably you would still need to `strip()` the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the start/end delimiters are in lookaround constructs in your pattern and thus will remain in the resulting string after `re.sub`. You should convert the lookbehind and lookahead into consuming patterns.

Also, you seem to want to remove special chars after the right hand delimiter, so you need to add `[^\w\s]*` at the end of the regex.

You may use

```
import re
text = """|start| this is first para to remove |end|.
this is another text.
|start| this is another para to remove |end|. Again some free text"""
print( re.sub(r'(?s)\|start\|.*?\|end\|[^\w\s]*', '', text).replace('\n', '') )
# => this is another text. Again some free text
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KzOX2f).

**Regex details**

- `(?s)` - inline DOTALL modifier
- `\|start\|` - `|start|` text
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\|end\|`  - `|end|` text
- `[^\w\s]*` - 0 or more chars other than word and whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import re

your_string = """|start| this is first para to remove |end|.
this is another text.
|start| this is another para to remove |end|. Again some free text"""

regex = r'(\|start\|).+(\|end\|\.)'

result = re.sub(regex, '', your_string).replace('\n', '')

print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
this is another text. Again some free text
```