# match all characters until any character in a set

Tags: regex

With

```
test(test) =
```

I want to match

```
test(
```

With

```
test = test
```

I want to match

```
test =
```

I tried this regex

```
/.+[\(=]/
```

but it will give the whole string for

test(test) =

instead of

test(

Comment: This is just a greedy vs. lazy matching issue.  Add a `?` to your greedy quantifier to make it lazy, like so: `/.+?[\(=]/`

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong thanks I searched all over google but couldn't find it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between .\*? and .\* regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions)