# string with &lt;tag_name&gt; replace with null

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm just trying to replace the following text without the HTML part like this

```
designed to display special types of text:&lt;b&gt;- Bold text&lt;strong&gt;&nbsp;- Important text&lt;i&gt;&nbsp;- Italic text&lt;em&gt;&nbsp;- Emphasized text&lt;mark&gt;&nbsp;-
```

using this regular expression replace all between `&lt;` and `&gt;` with empty

```
html = html.replace("/(&lt;\/*\w+?&gt;)/g", '');
```

but my regular expression seems not working, how to get exact one ?

Comment: You're missing the `/` for a start - which would be shown in your browser console.  But sounds like an XY problem - where did you get the original string from?

Comment: I got from this page https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp, I just updated the regular expression '(&lt;\/*\w+?&gt;)'

Comment: Ok - so it's just a string defined in your code (`var html = '...'`) - if you were using jquery to get it from the page, eg `$("#id").html()` then the simple solution would be to use `$("#id").text()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `()` grouping if you're not going to use the groups.   A relatively simple regex will suffice:

- match `&lt;`
- match any number of characters, [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions) `.*?`
- match `&gt;`
- apply to all `g`
- replace with `''`

```js
var html = 'designed to display special types of text:&lt;b&gt;- Bold text&lt;strong&gt;&nbsp;- Important text&lt;i&gt;&nbsp;- Italic text&lt;em&gt;&nbsp;- Emphasized text&lt;mark&gt;&nbsp;- ';
console.log(html.replace(/&lt;.*?&gt;/g, ''));
```

**Caveat** note that parsing HTML with regex is not robust.  It might work in your scenario, but it's *very* easy to break / provide a string where it doesn't work.