# How to use regex to query if my data have many special character like this

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data like this in DB and can not change the value at all
`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63932a20be6f9527c79432d0"),
    "userId" : "123456789",
    "message" : "{\"badge\":\"10\",\"timeToLive\":86400.0,\"message\":\"Your full speed Internet has 200 MB remaining\",\"eventName\":\"default\",\"sender\":\"SRFC-DataPolicy\",\"contentDetail\":{\"actionLink\":\"http://www.ais.co.th/push-notify_aisapp/before_used_up_post_unlimit.html?mb=300 MB \",\"inboxFlag\":true},\"dataMessage\":{\"displaySize\":{\"unit\":\"percent\",\"height\":95.0,\"width\":95.0},\"mediaDataList\":[{\"mediaNo\":1.0,\"mediaType\":\"webview\",\"mediaExtension\":\"html\",\"mediaUrl\":\"http://www.ais.co.th/push-notify_aisapp/before_used_up_post_unlimit.html?mb=300 MB \"}]}}",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2022-11-01T11:00:02.526+0000"),
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2022-11-01T11:00:02.526+0000")
}
```

`
I want to query using regex for **mediaUrl** in key **message**

This is my current query

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection").find({message:{$regex: '300 MB'}})
```

But if some data have **message** '300 MB' It will show up, I just want it to show only '300 MB' in **mediaUrl** in key **message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection").find({message:{$regex: 'mediaUrl.*?300 MB'}})
```

The dot (`.`) means any character and the asterisk (`*`) means any number of times (including 0). The question mark (`?`) makes it [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions). So it matches the text `mediaUrl` followed by any number of characters and stops when it finds `300 MB`.

I highly recommend something like: https://regex101.com/ to try out regex and learn.

Comment: It worked on mediaUrl but when I need to query 'message' 300 MB in message key, 300 MB in mediaUrl show up too.

Comment: there is no 300 MB in message, it is 200 MB. If you do `message.*200 MB` you get what I think you want.. however, I edited the answer to be `.*?` which should catch the least amount of text possible while still matching, that should also help